# Add multiple included dynamically

Tags: entity-framework-6

I put together some helpers that will allow me to register includes by type.  Looks like this:

```
Dictionary<Type, LambdaExpression[]> includes = 
    new Dictionary<Type, LambdaExpression[]>();
```

I register includes like this:

```
public void Add<T>(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
{
    this.includes.Add(typeof(T), includes);
}

Add<Customer>(e => 
    e.Address.City.Province.Country,
    e.Products.Select(p => p.Category));
```

Notice there are two includes for `Customer`.  I then have this method that gets includes by type:

```
DbSet<T> entitySet = null;

void LoadIncludes()
{
    var includes = Includes.Instance.Get<T>().DirectCast<Expression<Func<T, object>>[]>();

    if (includes != null)
    {
        foreach (var include in includes)
        {
            entitySet.Include(include).Load();
        }
    }
}
```

When getting my entity, I do this:

```
public T GetById(int id)
{
    LoadIncludes();

    return entitySet.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
}
```

It works well, but it's so slow, and it's because of the `.Load()` method I am calling in `LoadIncludes()`.  Is there a faster way to do what I want to do here?

Comment: I guess I could use expressions to create/compile a type-specific delegate at runtime to call `.Include()` consecutively for every include in the collection.  I will do that and post the code if no one has a better solution.

Comment: What is `entitySet`?

Comment: @IvanStoev Oops... it's `DbSet<T>`. Will update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't call `Load`, but build and use a `Queryable<T>` with `Include` chain.

Replace `LoadIncludes` with private function:

```
private IQueryable<T> GetEntitySet()
{
    var set = entitySet.AsQueryable();
    var includes = Includes.Instance.Get<T>().DirectCast<Expression<Func<T, object>>[]>();
    if (includes != null)
    {
        foreach (var include in includes)
        {
            set = set.Include(include);
        }
    }
    return set;
}
```

and use it as follows:

```
public T GetById(int id)
{
    return GetEntitySet().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
}
```

Comment: Amazing!  It's blazing fast.  I believe you've helped me several times before on EF and expression trees, so thanks again.